# Spreadsheet timestamp script skipping rows

Tags: javascript, timestamp, spreadsheet

I created a script that normally would generate a timestamp for first edit and last edit on columns 27 and 28, my problem is that some rows don't activate the script and I don't understand why.

I am having an issue with the following script :

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Timestamps(e);
};

function Timestamps(e) {
  
  // **Variables - Range of edit modifications**
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  // **Variables - Starting row and tab selected**
  var startRow = 2;
  var tab = "TP";
  
  // **Columns - Columns that trigger the timestamp**
  if( e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === tab && row >= startRow && col === 12 ||
     e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === tab && row >= startRow && col === 13 ||
     e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === tab && row >= startRow && col === 14 ||
     e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === tab && row >= startRow && col === 15 ||
     e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === tab && row >= startRow && col === 16 ||
     e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === tab && row >= startRow && col === 17 ||
     e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === tab && row >= startRow && col === 18 ||
     e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === tab && row >= startRow && col === 19 ||
     e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === tab && row >= startRow && col === 20 ||
     e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === tab && row >= startRow && col === 21 ||
     e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === tab && row >= startRow && col === 22 ||
     e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === tab && row >= startRow && col === 23  
    ){
      var currentDate = new Date();
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,28).setValue(currentDate);
        if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,27).getValue() == "" ){
          e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,27).setValue(currentDate);
        } // **END IF - Check if date created exists**
    } // **END IF - Check column, row and tab**
}; // **END Timestamps function**
```

Any insight would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you certain the Values in question for column 27 are set to "" in the missing rows, and not some other value, like whitespace or null? I also don't see a loop here, so I'm not entirely sure when you would do anything that could "skip" rows, unless the row hasn't been edited?

Comment: Yes, all values are "" in column 27, but even if values are there it should overwrite and place the timestamp. I select the row in question and try to edit the rows and nothing, it seems to only apply timestamp to certain rows.